# HTML snippets recognized in blade files

Tags: laravel, vim, laravel-blade

For a while now I've been trying to expand HTML snippets (using Ultisnips) in *.blade.php files. I think I've tried everything but nothing seems to work properly.
Do you know how to achieve this? Working with HTML inside a blade file without having HTML snippets is really tough.

Edit:

Here is what I've tried so far:

- `extends html` in the `php.snippets` file as it seems to be the recommended way of doing it.
- `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.php set ft=html | set ft=php` and `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.blade.php set ft=blade.html.php` (even though I don't really understand what that's supposed to do)

These are the two methods that I've seen so far. None of them actually let me expand the HTML snippets.

Comment: Please define "everything".

Comment: Let me edit my ticket first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is 7 months late, but I stumbled across this from Google. Here's what worked for me.

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.blade.php setlocal ft=html
```

Comment: You just saved me. Thanks so much.